# Replicate Ploltly chart with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly

Shown below is a treemap created with Plotly. You can find the corresponding code and chart below.

I appreciate the style of this graph and aim to replicate it using ggplot2. Below, you'll see a treemap generated with ggplot2.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)
library(dplyr)

df1<-structure(list(manuf = c("AMC", "Cadillac", "Camaro", "Chrysler", 
                              "Datsun", "Dodge", "Duster", "Ferrari", "Fiat", "Ford", "Honda", 
                              "Hornet", "Lincoln", "Lotus", "Maserati", "Mazda", "Merc", "Pontiac", 
                              "Porsche", "Toyota", "Valiant", "Volvo"), count = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                                                                  1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 7L, 1L, 1L, 
                                                                                  2L, 1L, 1L)), row.names = c(NA, -22L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
                                                                                                                                   "data.frame"))
df1$test<-"CARS"

treemap<-plot_ly(data = df1,
                 type= "treemap",
                 values= ~count,
                 labels= ~manuf,
                 parents=  ~test,
                 domain= list(column=0),
                 name = " ",
                 textinfo="label+value+percent parent")  %>%
  layout(title="", 
         annotations =
           list(x = 0, y = -0.1,
                title = "", 
                text = " ",
                showarrow = F,
                xref='paper',
                yref='paper'))

treemap
```

[image]

However, I'm encountering difficulty reproducing the **white lines or empty space** that separate the rectangles in Plotly within ggplot2.
Below you can see  my Treemap with ggplot2.

```
library(treemapify)
library(ggplot2)

group <- paste("Group", 1:9)
subgroup <- c("A", "C", "B", "A", "A",
              "C", "C", "B", "B")
value <- c(7, 25, 50, 5, 16,
           18, 30, 12, 41)

df <- data.frame(group, subgroup, value) 

# Calculate percentage share for each group
df$percentage <- df$value / sum(df$value) * 100

test_treemap<-ggplot(df, aes(area = percentage, fill = group, label = paste(subgroup, ": ", value, " (", round(percentage, 2), "%)"))) +
  geom_treemap() +
  geom_treemap_text(colour = "white",
                    hjust = "left",
                    #place = "left",
                    size = 8,
                    fontface = "bold") +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Set1")+
  labs(title = "Treemap with Percentage Share by Group")+
  theme(legend.position = "none")
```

[image]

Could someone assist me in achieving this effect(white line or empty spaces) between rectangles ?

Comment: Did you glance at the `treemapify` docs? This is a really minor modification to my answer to your almost [identical question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78223805/cloning-treemap-from-plotly-to-ggplot2/78223890) earlier today.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add an outline using `color=` and `size=` in `geom_treemap`. I also added some linebreaks to your labels and some more padding:

```r
library(treemapify)
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(
  df,
  aes(
    area = percentage, fill = group,
    label = paste0(subgroup, ":\n", value, "\n", round(percentage, 2), "%")
  )
) +
  geom_treemap(color = "white", size = 4) +
  geom_treemap_text(
    colour = "white",
    size = 8,
    fontface = "bold",
    padding.x = unit(2, "mm"),
    padding.y = unit(2, "mm")
  ) +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Set1") +
  labs(title = "Treemap with Percentage Share by Group") +
  theme(legend.position = "none")
```

[image]